# Facebook 2014: how to create a simple page with an iframe inside?

Tags: facebook

I've looked tons of guide and youtube tutorial. But it seems very hard to create a simple empty page with an Iframe inside that links to another web site.

Do you know how to do it?

I need something like this: https://www.facebook.com/betfred/app_336839629721636
But it seems it needs the https url. And I don't have it.

[image]

Comment: Facebook wanted to cease http support long time ago. Now they did. You can only use secure urls as of 2014. Check out https://www.heroku.com/ which provides free hosting with ssl

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What you're trying to do is **Creating A Page Tab**

Click the <kbd>Add Platform</kbd> button, then select the platform you're working on and config it

[image: Adding platform]

Click "Page Tab"

[image: Adding page tab]

Put your URL in "Page Tab Url" field and as you can see **you need to provide a "secure page tab url"**

Save your changes

[image: Configuring Page tab]

Next to add the app to your page with "[Add Page Tab](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page)" Dialog

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&redirect_uri=https://facebook.com
```

Resource:

- [Page Tab Tutorial - Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/)
- [Add Page Tab Dialog - Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page)

Comment: I thank you one million times, I had found thousand facebook tutorial and 3rd parties apps to make iframe but no one was ok..

Comment: You may need a `redirect_uri` parameter too, like this: `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://www.YOURSITE.com/`

Comment: Accessing Page Tab URL of your is not working, do you have a updated one?